# No exact matches in call initializer

Tags: swiftui

I don't understand why this don't work

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let someDate = Date()
        let timeStamp = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let myStamp = Int(timeStamp)
        
        ZStack {     //: 01
            VStack(spacing: 20) { //: 02
            
            Text(now, style: .date)     //: date
               .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Spacer()
            
       
            Text(myStamp)
           
                
            } //: end of vstack 02
        } //: end of Zstack 01
    } //: end of some view
} //: end of content view
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example code. Note, use `.now` to represent a `Date`, and `myStamp` is of type `Int`, which you need to convert to a `String` for use in `Text()`
using the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let someDate = Date()
        let timeStamp = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let myStamp = Int(timeStamp)
        
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(.now, style: .date)  // <-- here, or use `someDate`
               .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Spacer()
            Text("\(myStamp)") // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would gain a lot by doing the tutorial again at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

So basically, the error is telling you that in `Text(_ date: Date, style: Text.DateStyle)`, the first argument must be a `Date`, but you have `now` which does not exist or represent a Date. However `.now` represents a date, and so all works without errors. Similarly for `Text(myStamp)`, in this case `Text()` expect a `String`. So you can use the code as shown, or use for example `Text(String(myStamp))` to turn `myStamp` into a `String`.

Comment: did my answer not work for you?